# Does my formula work? (Can it be shortened?)

Tags: trigonometry, angle

I made a formula for converting reference angle to degrees from initial side to terminal side:

$$\left\lvert90(\,Mod\left(Mod(Q\, ,\, 2\right)+ 1\,,2)) - Θ\right\rvert + 90(Q-1)$$
Where Θ is the reference angle
$\qquad$ and $\qquad$
Q is the quadrant (an integer 1 through 4)

I've done some testing, and I'm fairly certain it works with minutes and seconds as well, but I figured it would be good to get smarter people's opinions. 
[also, is there a way to shorten this possibly?]

EDIT: Woah, thanks for that Blue, I guess while fidgeting around with the aesthetics, I forgot the 90!, and yes Jens, Theta represents any angle $ 0° \le \Theta \le 90° $

Comment: Your objective is unclear to me. Are you trying to convert an angle $\le 90^\circ$ in a given quadrant to an angle in the interval [0,360]?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're aiming for. Does $\Theta + 90(Q - 1)$ do what you want? If not, it would help to say what you mean by a "reference angle from initial side to terminal side". :)